# Guardar e aceder a dados de estruturas dentro de estruturas

Tags: c

Boa noite! Estou a aprender a programar em c e estou com um problema, alguém me pode ajudar?

```
typedef struct utente //Armazena o nome, número de utente, data de nascimento de um utente, assim como se se trata de um utente de rsico ou não
{

    int num;
    char nome[27];
    char nascimento[11];
    char risco;

} utente_tipo;

typedef struct concelho //Armazena o nome, código e número de habitantes de um concelho
{
    char nome[30];
    int code;
    int habitantes;

} concelho_tipo;

typedef struct rastreio
{
    utente_tipo utente;
    concelho_tipo concelho;
    char data[11];
    char teste;
    char sintomas[40];
} rastreio_tipo;
```

Como devo guardar e aceder aos dados da estrutura rastreio?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua dúvida, seria algo do tipo `rastreio_tipo.utente.num` ou `rastreio_tipo.concelho.habitantes`?

Comment: Exato, a minha dúvida é exatamente como faço a articulação entre as três estruturas, ou seja, como aceder aos dados habitantes, risco e assim das estruturas utente_tipo e concelho_tipo através da rastreio_tipo

Comment: Pelo que entendo cada instância de `rastreio_tipo` deveria ter múltiplos `concelho`s e `utente`s associados, mas sua declaração só associa apenas um `concelho` e um `utente` a `rastreio_tipo`.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor por favor? Não percebi porque tem que ser assim...